# How to read multiple checkboxes(and data associated with it)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes and each checkbox as an input field associated with it that'll activate once you check the checkbox.

I've got the frontend working just fine, but I was wondering how can I read in my PHP which checkboxes were checked along with their respective input fields (and some have a radio button too in addition to the input field)

Here's what each individual checkbox in my form looks like:

```
 <!-- Option1 -->
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" onchange="showqt()" value="Button Chicken Amritsari" id="c1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="c1">
                      Button Chicken Amritsari<i><br>(Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="ifYes" style="display: none; float:right;">
                    <!-- <label for="qtcounter">Quantity:</label> -->
                    <div class="input-group" id="qtcounter">
                      <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                      <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="quantity" class="quantity-field">
                      <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Option 1 ends -->
```

I haven't wrapped my head around the PHP yet but previously to read multiple checkboxes I put them all in an array in the `name` field and read that array in PHP. However, that was without the added complication of each checkbox having input field.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you use ajax ?

Comment: It'd be best to avoid it as much as possible @Swati

Comment: I don't have the whole context but make sure your example is wrapped in <form> element. Also, form values are sent to server via their respective `name` attribute as a key but I don't see `name` attribute in your checkbox element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use an associative array for both the inputs and the checkboxes.

```html
<!-- Option1 -->
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input showman" type="checkbox" name="items[1][chosen]" onchange="showqt()" value="Button Chicken Amritsari" id="c1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="c1">
        Button Chicken Amritsari<i><br>(Boneless) Serves 2<br>INR 290</i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="ifYes" style="display: none; float:right;">
      <!-- <label for="qtcounter">Quantity:</label> -->
      <div class="input-group" id="qtcounter">
        <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="items[1][quantity]">
        <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" name="items[1][quantity]" class="quantity-field">
        <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="items[1][quantity]">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Option 1 ends -->
```

For option 2 use `items[2][chosen]` and `items[2][quantity]`, etc.

Note that must specify the index and can't use `[]`. Otherwise, the index of `quantity` will not match the chosen item.

In php you can loop through the items and ignore the items that aren't chosen.

```php
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) {
    if (!isset($item['chosen'])) continue; // Skip items that aren't chosen.

    echo $item['quantity'] . ' ' . $item['chosen'] . "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Let me run this through and get back to you

Comment: This only reads the first item in the list. The others don't get read even after being checked

Comment: @YaddyVirus this answer is correct. I think you forgot to edit the other item's related fields name.
name="items[1][quantity]"for first checkbox, name="items[2][quantity]" for second one and etc...

Comment: @Akinak I used the answer exactly as is. Turns out the isse was something else